# Accessing on, visit, and if methods from inside PageObject class

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a Cucumber/Watir/PageObject project set up. I am trying to set the @current_page variable outside of the step_definitions inside of the actual page-object. No matter what I do, I get the error

`` undefined method `on' for #<TestPage:0x45044d0> (NoMethodError) ``

---

#### test_page.rb

```rb
# coding: utf-8

## Test module
class TestPage < AnotherTestPage
  include PageObject

  div(:test_button, id: 'testbutton')

  #
  # Opens test page 2
  #
  # @param [Boolean] test_button defaults to false. If true, the Test button will be selected
  # @return [PageObject] the newly created Test2Page page object
  #
  def open_test2(test_button=false)
    test_button.click if test_button
    on(Test2Page)
  end

end
```

---

#### test_steps.rb

```rb
And(/^the Test2 screen is visible$/) do
  @current_page.open_test2
end
```

---

I've tried `include`ing and `extend`ing both `PageObject::PageFactory` and `PageNavigation`, and neither worked. I also tried adding `World(TestPage)` and `World(TestPage.new)` to the bottom of the TestPage file. That also did not work, seemingly because `TestPage` is a class.

My question therefore is, how can I set the `@current_page` variable ***inside of my PageObject and outside of the step definitions***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `on` method in the page object, you need to include the `PageObject::PageFactory`:

```
# Page that calls the on method
class MyPage
  include PageObject
  include PageObject::PageFactory

  def do_stuff
    on(MyPage2)
  end
end

# Page that is returned by the on method
class MyPage2
  include PageObject
end

# Script that calls the methods and shows that the on method works
browser = Watir::Browser.new
page = MyPage.new(browser)
current_page = page.do_stuff
p current_page.class
#=> MyPage2
```

However, there is no way for the page object to change the `@current_page` that is used by the Cucumber steps. The page objects have no knowledge of the Cucumber instance's `@current_page` variable. I think you will have to manually assign the page:

```
And(/^the Test2 screen is visible$/) do
  @current_page = @current_page.open_test2
end
```

Note that this assumes that `open_test2` is returning a page object, which it currently does (ie the `on` method returns a page object).

Comment: I had `included` `PageObject::PageFactory` but I didn't think about just returning the PageObject and then setting it on the cucumber side. I didn't realize that @current_page was only viewable to the Cucumber instance. Does that mean it's accessible by anything in `World`? Because you can add modules to `World`, can you not? So therefore if my class was instead a module, and I added it to `World` would I then have access to the `@current_page` variable?

Comment: I guess the short answer is "yes", as that is exactly what the PageObject::PageFactory does. However, turning your page object class into a module is unlikely to work.